# Plot DataFrame with Strings into stacked bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

Following situation:

I have a dataframe (df) with the following scheme:

|  | Gender | AgeGroup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | m | Group1 |
| 1 | m | Group2 |
| 2 | f | Group2 |
| 3 | f | Group1 |

I want to do a stacked bar chart using pandas & matplotlib, with the age groups on the x axis and the amount of genders on a stacked bar on the y-axis.

I tried plotting it with various:

```
df.plot.bar(column=["AgeGroup", "Gender"], stacked=True)
```

But I always get the error that there are no numeric values inside the dataframe, which makes sense, but I am trying to count those.

What would the ideal solution be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(df['AgeGroup'], df['Gender']).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]